# Python3 how to declare global variables for "For" loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

So I'm trying to have global variables that are going to be used within a For loop. This code works without error when not in a function "def" but I need it to be as I'm attempting to create a tkinter file dialog box which runs the code once file is chosen if you can either help tell me what I am doing wrong or give me an alternative to using tkinter and a "def".

Working Code:

```
import os
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime
# import datetime
import itertools
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
date = datetime.strptime('1991-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
f_path = 'C:/Users/Lewis Collins/Job_Code/data/cru_ts_2_10.1991-2000_cutdown.pre'

# db = sqlite3.connect('output.db')
# cursor = db.cursor()
# cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE Rainfall (Xref, Yref, Date, Value)')
# date = datetime.date(1991,1,1)

flag = 0

Xref = ''

Yref = ''

with open(f_path) as file_read:

    for row in itertools.islice(file_read, 5, None):
        # print(row)
        if 'Grid-ref' in row:
            Xref = row.split(',')[0].split('=   ')[1]
            Yref = row.split(',')[1]
            date = datetime.strptime('1990-12-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
        else:
            for Value in row.split():
                date = date + relativedelta(months=+1)
                # print(Xref.strip(), Yref.strip(), date, Value)

                # print(Xref, Yref, date, Value)

# db.commit()
# db.close()
```

Edited Code:

```
import tkinter
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import itertools

#date = datetime.strptime('1991-01-01', '%y-%m-%d')

# date = datetime.strptime('1991-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
f_path = 'C:/Users/Lewis Collins/Job_Code/data/cru_ts_2_10.1991-2000_cutdown.pre'
Xref = ''
Yref = ''



def read_date():

    with open(f_path) as file_read:

        for row in itertools.islice(file_read, 5, None):

            if 'Grid-ref' in row:
                Xref = row.split(',')[0].split('=   ')[1]
                Yref = row.split(',')[1]
                date = datetime.strptime('1990-12-01', '%y-%m-%d')
            else:
                for Value in row.split():
                    date = date + relativedelta(months=+1)
                    print(Xref.strip(), Yref.strip(), date, Value)
```

Comment: Don't use a global variable. Have your function `return` the result instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***PS using global variables is not recommended use them only if its your last way***

add global keyword in your function like this

```
my_blobal_var
my_blobal_var2

def my_func():
    global my_blobal_var
    global my_blobal_var2
    do_something()
```

for your case

```
Xref = ''
Yref = ''

def read_date():
      global Xref
      global Yref
      do_your_thing()
```

Comment: When i do this i receive a new error which again i don't quite get as like i have previously stated the code is near identical to original i will add changes along with error

Comment: or actually sorry this will be a violation as question has been answered

Comment: I don't know if it's a violation or not but if your question is solved mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a global variable. It's almost always a mistake. Pass arguments to your function and have it return the results:

```
def read_date(path):
    xref = ''
    yref = ''
    with open(path) as file_read:
        for row in itertools.islice(file_read, 5, None):
            if 'Grid-ref' in row:
                xref = row.split(',')[0].split('=   ')[1]
                yref = row.split(',')[1]
                date = datetime.strptime('1990-12-01', '%y-%m-%d')
            else:
                for Value in row.split():
                    date = date + relativedelta(months=+1)
                    print(Xref.strip(), Yref.strip(), date, Value)
    return xref, yref, date, Value
```

This way, `xref`, `yref`, … are local variables inside your `read_date` function. When it is done, it returns their value to the caller. It also takes the file path as an argument instead of it being tied to a global variable. You would call it like this:

```
Xref, Yref, date, Value = read_date(f_path)
```

**Note:** the actual useful data is not clear from your code sample. Simply return whatever results you care about and collect them **in the same order** when calling the function.

Comment: I need `Xref    Yref    date    Value` as my next step is adding them to a database in 4 columns, what does this bottom section of the code do could you explain it. Thanks

Comment: Updated. The call shows how to invoke your function from your main program. It passes `f_path` as the path to open, and puts the returned values into the four variables `Xref`, `Yref`, `date` and `Value`. (The actual process is called *unpacking*: a 4-tuple of values is unpacked into 4 variables.)